# What does $A = L + D + U$ look like?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, systems-of-equations

**Exercise:**

Consider the problem
\begin{split}
10u_1 + u_2 &= 1\\
u_1 + 10u_2 &= 10
\end{split}
with the solution $(u_1,u_2)^T = (0,1)^T$. For a general system of equations
$$Au = b$$
with an $n\times n$ matrix $A$, which consists of a lower triangular submatrix $L$, the diagonal $D$ and the uppertriangular submatrix $U\,(A=L+D+U)$, a Gauss–Seidel iteration is defined by $$u^{i+1} = D^{-1}(b - Lu^{i+1} - Uu^i)$$
and a Jacobi iteration is defined by $$u^{i+1} = D^{-1}(b - Lu^i - Uu^i)$$

Perform:

a) Four Gauss-Seidel iterations.

b) Four Jacobi iterations.

**Question:**

- What does $A = L + D + U$ mean? I suppose that I doesn't mean that $a_{ij} = l_{ij} + d_{ij} + u_{ij}$? If that *is* what it's supposed to mean, do we get $$L = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\
  1 &0 \end{bmatrix}, \,D = \begin{bmatrix}10 & 0\\
  0&10\end{bmatrix},\,U = \begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\
  0&0\end{bmatrix} $$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are correct. $L$, $D$ and $U$ are exactly the matrices you wrote and their sum is $A$.

Comment: Indeed you are absolutely correct. It is nice to see a well formatted question, including your own ideas. If you are interested in a more general approach to Gauß-Seidel and Jacobi-Iteration, have a look at [Saad's book](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/IterMethBook_2ndEd.pdf). Both methods can be seen in the more general framework of [additive splitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_splitting). [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1255790/what-is-the-intuition-behind-matrix-splitting-methods-jacobi-gauss-seidel) MSE-Question has also great answers.

Comment: @P.Siehr Thanks! Just one quick question about the gauss-seidel iterations: do you have to calculate $L,D,U$ etc, after each iteration?

Comment: No, since both iterations don't change $A$. And you don't "calculate" them at all, as they are already given. Don't confuse them with a multiplicative decomposition, such as $LU$ or $QR$.

Comment: @P.Siehr I'm a bit confused trying to actually perform 4 Jacobi iterations! $u^i$ doesn't change. After each iteration I have $u^i = (0,1)$, is this correct?

Comment: Well what did you use as starting vector?

Comment: @P.Siehr I used $u^i  = (0,1)$

Comment: The Jacobi-Iteration is a fixed-point iteration. So if it converges, it will converge to the exact solution. And you entered the correct solution as starting vector.

Answer (score 1):

Your $L$, $D$, and $U$ are correct. Note that $a_{ij} = l_{ij} + d_{ij} + u_{ij}$  is true, however, two of the three terms are always zero; the upper right entry would be $a_{ij} = 0 + 0 + 1$.

In general, $\color{red}A = \color{blue}L + \color{orange}D + \color{green}U$ looks like
$$
\color{red}{\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \ldots & a_{1,n-1} & a_{1,n}
\\ a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \ldots & a_{2,n-1} & a_{2,n}
\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots
\\ a_{n-1,1} & a_{n-1,2} & \ldots & a_{n-1,n-1} & a_{n-1,n}
\\ a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & \ldots & a_{n,n-1} & a_{n,n}
\end{pmatrix}}
=\\
\color{blue}{\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0
\\ a_{2,1} & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0
\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots
\\ a_{n-1,1} & a_{n-1,2} & \ldots & 0 & 0
\\ a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & \ldots & a_{n,n-1} & 0
\end{pmatrix}}
+\\
\color{orange}{\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0
\\ 0 & a_{2,2} & \ldots & 0 & 0
\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots
\\ 0 & 0 & \ldots & a_{n-1,n-1} & 0
\\ 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & a_{n,n}
\end{pmatrix}}
+\\
\color{green}{\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a_{1,2} & \ldots & a_{1,n-1} & a_{1,n}
\\ 0 & 0 & \ldots & a_{2,n-1} & a_{2,n}
\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots
\\ 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & a_{n-1,n}
\\ 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}}
$$

Note that in this case $L$ and $U$ are *strictly* triangular matrices. A triangular matrix may have non-zero entries in its diagonal, e.g.: $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ is an upper triangular matrix (but not a strictly upper triangular matrix).